# Is there any way to use Django templates in Webapp2 framework in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates, webapp2

I am using Django 1.2 template tags over webapp framework in Google App engine. I intend to migrate over to Webapp2.  I was looking for a way to this in webapp2, but did not find a template engine for webapp2. So, should I continue with webapp's template engine or use pure Django template engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people use Jinja templates with webapp2 in GAE, but you can also use Django templates.  The two template systems are very similar so it is fairly easy to switch between the two.

The template system that you use is quite independent of webapp2.  It works like this:

1. Render your template to get a string representation of your HTML page
2. Transmit the string with webapp2

Feel free to use Jinja, Django, or any other templating system.  Webapp2 doesn't provide templates because it is not part of its job.